# Don't require check for input field when back button is clicked

Tags: html

I have a required input, with two buttons "submit" and "goBack". On clicking "goBack", I don't want to require check for the input field. 
Belpw is the code I tried,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="nameofcontract" placeholder="Name of Contract" required></form>

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button> 
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg " onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: when you need required check for input field, after press submit button or go back button ?

Answer (score 1):

by default a button is submit, so a click validates the form

change the type to "button" to change the behaviour

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

reducing your example to what is required

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function goBack() {
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/"
        }
        </script>

        <form>
            <input type="text" 
                name="nameofcontract" placeholder="Name of Contract" required>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>     
            <button type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

        </form>    

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this lines. **I hope this is what you like to achieve:**

```js
function goBack() {
  if (!formGroupExampleInput.value) return;
  console.log("goBack")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="nameofcontract" placeholder="Name of Contract" required>

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg " onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

set Id of both button and check blank on click

$('#Submit').click(function(){

if($('#formGroupExampleInput').val()=='')
{

alert('can not blank')

return false;

}

else

{

alert('ok')

return true;
}

})

$('#goback').click(function()

{

window.location.href='your url';

})